# SocialAuth - Can't get location through Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, socialauth

I am currently attempting to generate a user profile in an Android application through the users existing social network data. I am using the SocialAuth library to login and pull the data out of the application and populate some text fields in a fragment.

I am currently using Facebook and Twitter for this but I am having trouble reciving the "Location" of the profile through Facebook. Twitter is able to get location successfully but Facebook simply comes up "Null" when the get request is sent out.

To complicate things when I access the Facebook account I am testing on with the example application that SocialAuth provides it is able to get the location without any problems but despite my code being identical and Twitter running the same code it won't work within my application.

Can anyone shed some light on why I am unable to retrieve the location through Facebook in my application? I will provide my relevant classes below:

LoginActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.brickred.socialauth.android.DialogListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Profile;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    private Button facebook_button;
    private Button twitter_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

        facebook_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbSignUp);
        twitter_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.twitSignUp);

        facebook_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.FACEBOOK);
            }
        });

        twitter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.TWITTER);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {
            adapter.getUserProfileAsync(new ProfileDataListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBack() {

        }
    }

    private class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener<Profile> {
        @Override
        public void onExecute(String provider, Profile t) {

            Profile profileMap = t;

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HubPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("provider", provider);
            intent.putExtra("profile", profileMap);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {

        }
    }
}
```

Profile Fragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.brickred.socialauth.Profile;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    Profile profileMap;

    // Android Components
    TextView name;
    TextView location;
    ImageView image;

    // Variables
    String provider_name;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader;


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hub_page, container, false);

        profileMap = (Profile) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("profile");
        Log.d("Profile", "Validate ID = " + profileMap.getValidatedId());
        Log.d("Profile", "First Name  = " + profileMap.getFirstName());
        Log.d("Profile", "Last Name   = " + profileMap.getLastName());
        Log.d("Profile", "Location    = " + profileMap.getLocation());
        Log.d("Profile", "Profile Image URL  = " + profileMap.getProfileImageURL());

        provider_name = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("provider");

        // Set title
        name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        location = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profileLocation);
        image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ProfileActivity.this);

        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(profileMap.getProfileImageURL(), image);

        // Name
        if (profileMap.getFullName() == null)
            name.setText(profileMap.getFirstName() + profileMap.getLastName());
        else
            name.setText(profileMap.getFullName());

        // Location
        location.setText(profileMap.getLocation());

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find any solution despite hours of trying.